# High power consumption with 0% GPU utilization

Tags: gpu, power-consumption

How comes the graphic card's power consumption is sometime quite high while the GPU utilization is 0% (according to `nvidia-smi`'s output)?

E.g.:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

these cards have power saving capabilities but they may not be implemented in the driver you have installed, especially if it's a linux driver.